# Progress bar not working with javascript and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning bootstrap 4 and I saw progress bar.So, i though to make it more iteractive using javascript. But,my progress bar is not working.I want to move the progress bar upto 100%,like we see normal progress bar moving from 0% to 100%.
I tried :

```js
 var count=0;
    var x=document.querySelector('.progress-bar');
     
    window.onload=callMe();
    ;
    function callMe(){
        x.style.width=null;
         setInterval(function(){
              increaseBar();  
        },1000); 
    }


    function increaseBar(){
        count=count+10;
        console.log(count);
        console.dir(x);
       
       x.style.width=count;
      
        x.innerHTML=count;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Progress Bar With Label</h2>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" style="width:0%">0%</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
<script>
   
</script>
</html>
```

i see that x.style.width=count; is not working and i also tried using **x.setAttribute("style,"width")**,but it also didnot worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use percentage for with and clear interwal when reach 100 as percentage

```js
var count=0;var myVar;
    var x=document.querySelector('.progress-bar');         
    window.onload=callMe();
    ;
    function callMe(){
        x.style.width=null;
         myVar=setInterval(function(){
              increaseBar();  
        },1000); 
    }
    function increaseBar(){
       if(count==100){clearInterval(myVar);return}
        count=count+10;         
       x.style.width=count+"%";          
        x.innerHTML=count+"%";
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Progress Bar With Label</h2>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" style="width:0%">0%</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
<script>
   
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: oh we need % there?

Comment: yes your width is related percentage. I also add clear interval when reach 100% percentage  @Randomguy